# If A = 2, then set B to yes

Tags: sharepoint-online

Say, I have a SharePoint list with 2 columns, A and B.
A contains a list with three items: choice 1, choice 2 and choice 3.
B is a yes/no (true/false) field.

I would like to formulate an condition that does this:
If A = 2, then set B to yes.

I am new to the formulas, hence the question. I tried some things like: `=If([A]="2","true", "false")` Did not work.

Comment: In which column did you apply this formula ? can you use simple SPD workflow?

Comment: I applied the formula in column B. I haven't tried to use the workflow because i would first like to practice some more in formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading all your comments and inputs. I will suggest you to use below approach:

1. Create a new calculated column with name **B** (or whatever the real name you want to give it).
2. In the formula section use the below formula:

```
=IF([Functie]="Stagiair",TRUE,FALSE)
```

**Calculated Column Settings**:

[image]

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Select **The data type returned from this formula is** in your calculated field settings as **Yes/No**.

**Official documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. That was the solution. I needed to use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,). Thanks!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will be easy for others to find the correct solution easily in future.

Answer (score 4):

Your A column is choice field with Choices (1, 2, 3).

Your B column is Calculated field with type Yes/No.

For B column calculation formula is:

```
=IF(A="2",TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]

Column A

[image]

FINAL

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are close, but you only need to enclose your values in quotes if you need the values evaluated as strings.
 Assuming you configured column `'A'` as a numeric field type, and you have configured '`B'` as a Calculated column with a Boolean (yes/no) output, then the following should work:

```
=If([A]=2, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work. After I try to save it, it says that the formula has an syntaxerror. The column A is called Functie, and one of the values to choose from is Stagiair. So the're strings. I This should do it, right?

=If(Functie="Stagiair",TRUE, FALSE)

Comment: Yes, although you probably have to put the column name in square brackets, like `=IF([Functie]="Stagiair", TRUE, FALSE)`